# Kompose for docker-compose not use volumes

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

I use Kompose to convert docker-compose to Kubernetes files. When I used images runned on Docker (no Kubernetes), it used postgres volume to have persistent data. Now, with the same docker-compose, if I run with Kubernetes using the file created with Kompose, every time I launch Kubernetes the database is empty.
How is this possible? If I look at Docker Desktop, in fact, I see that the volumes do not have the tag "IN USE".

How do I do that?

**Thank you in advance!**

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  eureka-server:
    image: com.petcare/eureka-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: eureka-server
    expose:
      - 8761

  auth-service:
    image: com.petcare/auth-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: auth-service
    expose:
      - 8081
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - postgresqldb

  map-service:
    image: com.petcare/map-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: map-service
    expose:
      - 8082
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - postgresqldb

  reservation-service:
    image: com.petcare/reservation-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: reservation-service
    expose:
      - 8083
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - postgresqldb

  user-service:
    image: com.petcare/user-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: user-service
    expose:
      - 8084
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - postgresqldb

  api-gateway:
    image: com.petcare/api-gateway:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: api-gateway
    expose:
      - 8080
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
    labels:
      kompose.service.type: NodePort
      kompose.service.nodeport.port: "30000"

  postgresqldb:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=websitepetcare
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    labels:
      kompose.service.type: NodePort
      kompose.service.nodeport.port: "30002"

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 50
    ports:
      - "5050:50"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    links:
      - "postgresqldb:pgsql-server"
    depends_on:
      - postgresqldb
    labels:
      kompose.service.type: NodePort
      kompose.service.nodeport.port: "30001"

volumes:
  database-data:
    external: true
  pgadmin-data:
    external: true
```

**file created with kompose convert:**

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert -o kubernetes-services-deployments.yaml
        kompose.service.nodeport.port: "30001"
        kompose.service.type: NodePort
        kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: pgadmin
      name: pgadmin
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: pgadmin
      strategy:
        type: Recreate
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert -o kubernetes-services-deployments.yaml
            kompose.service.nodeport.port: "30001"
            kompose.service.type: NodePort
            kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            io.kompose.service: pgadmin
        spec:
          containers:
            - env:
                - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
                  value: admin@admin.com
                - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
                  value: root
                - name: PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT
                  value: "50"
              image: dpage/pgadmin4
              name: pgadmin4-container
              ports:
                - containerPort: 50
              resources: {}
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /var/lib/pgadmin
                  name: pgadmin-data
          restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - name: pgadmin-data
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: pgadmin-data
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: pgadmin-data
      name: pgadmin-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert -o kubernetes-services-deployments.yaml
        kompose.service.nodeport.port: "30002"
        kompose.service.type: NodePort
        kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: postgresqldb
      name: postgresqldb
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: postgresqldb
      strategy:
        type: Recreate
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert -o kubernetes-services-deployments.yaml
            kompose.service.nodeport.port: "30002"
            kompose.service.type: NodePort
            kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            io.kompose.service: postgresqldb
        spec:
          containers:
            - env:
                - name: POSTGRES_DB
                  value: websitepetcare
                - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
                  value: postgres
                - name: POSTGRES_USER
                  value: postgres
              image: postgres
              name: postgres
              ports:
                - containerPort: 5432
              resources: {}
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/
                  name: database-data
          restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - name: database-data
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: database-data
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: database-data
      name: database-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi
    status: {}
kind: List
metadata: {}
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?  (The Kubernetes YAML in particular is rather long, so removing the unnecessary Deployments and Services will help make this easier to read.)  When you say "every time I launch Kubernetes", what commands exactly are you running to restart this?  The Deployment/PersistentVolumeClaim structure looks okay (a StatefulSet would be a better match but I don't think Kompose knows how to generate those).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for the reply. I have modified the Kubernetes YAML file. Now there is only postgres and pgadmin. I do this: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml and then kubectl apply -f kubernetesFile.yaml And all the services are started correctly. When i want to delete all, i run this command: kubectl delete -f kubernetesFile.yaml When i start again all services with: kubectl apply -f kubernetesFile.yaml, I have the database empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you write:

> When I want to delete all, I run this command:
>
> ```sh
> kubectl delete -f kubernetesFile.yaml
> ```
>
> When I start again all services with:
>
> ```sh
> kubectl apply -f kubernetesFile.yaml
> ```
>
> I have the database empty.

The Kompose-converted `kubernetesFile.yaml` contains all of the Kubernetes resources, including the PersistentVolumeClaim that tells it to hold persistent data.  So when you `kubectl delete -f kubernetesFile.yaml`, it deletes the PersistentVolumeClaim and the data, and then when you re-`apply` it, you get a new empty volume.

You don't need to run `kubectl delete` here.  Just run `kubectl apply -f kubernetesFile.yaml` when your setup changes.  Anything that's updated will be changed, and the cluster will delete and recreate Pods as needed.  Anything that's not updated will stay unchanged.  If you delete a Deployment or another resource you'll have to delete that by hand (`kubectl delete deployment unused-deployment`).

Comment: Ok, I understand. But when i want to stop services, what can I do? Or just maybe when i want to turn off my computer, what i have to do? Because in this way, all the services are up, but when i want to stop them for any reasons, and then re-start them what i have to do?

Comment: You could `kubectl scale deployment NAME --replicas=0` to turn an individual deployment "off", or split the application and storage into separate YAML files and only undeploy the application half.

Comment: Ok right, this is a good tip. Maybe it's better to split application and storage, so i can stop all the application but not the storage. Is possible to do this with Kompose? I think no. With Kompose, i think that i can only split all files, and not into two different files. And when i turn off the computer? The volumes will be not empty?

Comment: In a comment I also suggested using a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) rather than a Deployment for the database.  This might match your setup better, since [deleting a StatefulSet doesn't delete its underlying storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-storage).  It looks like [the very most recent release of Kompose](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/releases/tag/v1.26.0) has all-or-nothing StatefulSet support; I might edit the generated YAML instead.

Comment: If you stop the cluster and restart it, its storage should stay available; depending on how you stopped it Pods might be recreated on new Nodes.  If you're on a single system and aren't looking at a clustered deployment then sticking with plain Compose might be easier.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to create the StatefulSet with Kompose? Maybe inserting something in the docker-compose?
As a cluster, i use the Kubernetes inside Docker Desktop. I don't know if when I close docker desktop the datas are still available. Ty very much anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240864/discussion-between-blowlore-and-david-maze).